# Set column value in each first matched row to 0

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, time-series, jupyter

I'm attempting to detect sequences of time where the difference between timestamps is below some threshold. To perform this I transform a list of timestamps into seconds and measure the difference between each time stamp. I've written code to perform this but the issue is when I measure differences between days the time difference value should be zero for the first row in each day. So the value `86390` in below dataframe should be 0. This is just a contrived example. For multiple groups how to set the first entry in each group to 0 ?

Code :

```
import pandas as pd

arr= []
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': ['2019-01-01 00:02:48.714000' , '2019-01-01 00:02:58.714000' , '2019-01-02 00:02:48.714000' , '2019-01-02 00:04:48.714000'],
     'id': [1 , 2 , 3 , 4],

    })
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

for d in df['date'] : 
    arr.append(d.timestamp())

df.sort_values(by=['date'])
df['TIME_IN_SEC'] = arr
df['TIME_IN_SEC_SHIFT'] = df.TIME_IN_SEC.shift(1)
df['TIME_DIFF'] = df["TIME_IN_SEC"] - df["TIME_IN_SEC_SHIFT"]

list_values = []

for g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='D')) : 
    list_values.append(sum(g[1]['TIME_DIFF']) / len(g[1]))

df
```

renders :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the first row of each day to zero, you can group by the date column but extract the actual date value, then aggregate to the 'first' row. Create a series from this for the 'id' column. (I'm assuming they are unique values.)

```
id_filt = df.groupby(df.date.dt.date).first()['id']
```

Then use loc to return only rows with the 'id' values, then set the columns equal to zero.

```
df.loc[df["id"].isin(id_filt.values), ["TIME_IN_SEC_SHIFT", "TIME_DIFF"]] = 0

                     date  id   TIME_IN_SEC  TIME_IN_SEC_SHIFT  TIME_DIFF
0 2019-01-01 00:02:48.714   1  1.546301e+09       0.000000e+00        0.0
1 2019-01-01 00:02:58.714   2  1.546301e+09       1.546301e+09       10.0
2 2019-01-02 00:02:48.714   3  1.546387e+09       0.000000e+00        0.0
3 2019-01-02 00:04:48.714   4  1.546387e+09       1.546387e+09      120.0
```

Of course you could combine these together to get:

```
df.loc[
    df["id"].isin(df.groupby(df.date.dt.date).first()["id"].values),
    ["TIME_IN_SEC_SHIFT", "TIME_DIFF"],
] = 0
```